# What is the best documentation for snapshots and flow repositories in Spring Web Flow?

Tags: java, spring, documentation, spring-webflow

I'm looking for more and better documentation about snapshots, flow repositories, and flow state serialization in Spring Web Flow.  Available docs I've found seem pretty sparse.  "Spring in Action" doesn't talk about this.  The Spring Web Flow Reference Manual does mention a couple flags here:

http://static.springframework.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#tuning-flow-execution-repository

but doesn't really talk about why you would change these settings, usage patterns, etc.

Anyone have a good reference?

Comment: Do you have any specific question about snaphots, flow repositories and flow state serialization? I don't know of any more detailed documentation than the Sprint references, which are not bad in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try out any of these books ?

1. http://www.ervacon.com/products/swfbook/index.html -- from the original author of WebFlow ?
2. [http://www.amazon.com/Expert-Spring-MVC-Web-Flow/dp/159059584X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059584X)

Comment: Thanks, those both seem to have some info from looking at TOC online.  From their age, I don't think either covers Web Flow 2 but that may not matter for my purposes.